# PHP 7 - IF statements doesn't seem to work while trying to detect KEYS in $_SESSION arrays

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, key, session-variables

[**PHP 7.1**]

Below you can see my PHP code. My problem comes from my difficult to understand why the second IF statement doesn't work with the array $_SESSION['items'], but does work with the testing array $zoo (I just created $zoo to make tests in place of $_SESSION['items']).

I've an AJAX script that send POST data to the PHP code and then logs the response to the browser console in order to let me review the results. Everything was working fine with my tests, all changes done to other arrays where executed with fine results, the only issue I couldn't understand and solve, even after extensively searching for some clues on the web and trying different things, is the misterious ways of the $_SESSION array that doesn't seem to like to expose its keys to lurking IF statements... And I got here trying to detect the existence of a key inside an array in order to increment its value. Something I already did before with other arrays that weren't $_SESSION arrays and it worked just fine.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['items'] = array();
$zoo['animals'] = array('tiger'=>2,'lion'=>3);

if(isset($_POST['item_name'])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['items'][$_POST['item_name']]) || array_key_exists($_POST['item_name'], $_SESSION['items'])) {
        $_SESSION['items'][$_POST['item_name']]['qnt']++;

    } else {
        $_SESSION['item_name'][$_POST['item_name']] = array('model'=>$_POST['item_model'], 'qnt'=>1);

    }

    echo json_encode($_SESSION['items']);

    exit();
  }
```

Comment: Is **item_model** being passed?

Comment: Please remove `$_SESSION['items'] = array();` see my answer.

Comment: @user2182349 yes it is! The AJAX script pass the data and receive the response to let me review the results on the browser console.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I changed the line you mentioned with your IF statement that checks if $_SESSION['items'] where already created and it worked! So, my intention to initialize it as an array without checking if it already existed made the code empty the array every single time that it received a POST from the AJAX script, right?

Comment: @DanielLimaPaulo - yes, that is correct.  As I said it's easy to miss because its a code logical error, not a coding error.  It's valid PHP but logically it doesn't work. Well it works how it's written, but not as it's intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified version of your code with just the important stuff

```
 session_start();

 $_SESSION['items'] = array(); //items is now emtpy

 if (isset($_SESSION['items'][$_POST['item_name']]) || array_key_exists($_POST['item_name'], $_SESSION['items'])) {

 }
```

This should make it a bit easier to see, so it's simply because `items` is an empty array.  Do to assigning it as such before the condition.

To fix it, either remove this line:

```
$_SESSION['items'] = array();
```

OR better yet:

```
$_SESSION['items'] = isset($_SESSION['items']) ? $_SESSION['items'] : [];
```

OR even

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['items'])) $_SESSION['items'] = [];
```

It's up to you how you fix it, but I am certain you don't want to reset that to an empty array.  It's a very easy mistake to make, and a hard one to find because it's technically legal PHP code.  I just have a built in debugger in my head now, from years of coding ... lol  ... Most times I can literally picture in my mind how something will execute.

Cheers!

Comment: As I stated in a comment up there, removing the $_SESSION['items'] = array(); line from the code seems to have made it stop being empty every time the AJAX script POSTed something to the PHP code. No just removing it, by the way, but actually changing it to the last line suggest by @ArtisticPhoenix.

Comment: Yea I wasn't sure what would work best in the code you are using, as I have little context to go on.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @artisticphoenix -

```
session_start();

// Check to see if there is a session variable before clearing it
// You only want to initialize it once
if (!isset($_SESSION['items'])) {
        $_SESSION['items'] = [];
}
$zoo['animals'] = array('tiger'=>2,'lion'=>3);

if(isset($_POST['item_name'])) {
        // This test is sufficient to check if the session variable has been set
        if (isset($_SESSION['items'][$_POST['item_name']])) {
                $_SESSION['items'][$_POST['item_name']]['qnt']++;
        } else {
                $_SESSION['items'][$_POST['item_name']] = array('model'=>$_POST['item_model'], 'qnt'=>1);

        }

        echo json_encode($_SESSION['items']);

        exit();
}
```

$_SESSION['item_name'] should be $_SESSION['items']